# Turning SQL expression into SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sql

I have this SQL expression that I'm trying to write in SQL Alchemy

```
select * from candidates1 c
inner join uploaded_emails1 e
    on c.id=e.candidate_id
group by e.thread_id
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: What have you tried? What results did you get? The best way for us to help you is to guide you in writing your own code, rather than writing it for you :)

Comment: In this example, you would need to create models, classes that map your database tables & relationships to SQLAlchemy models. Once you have your models defined, expressing your actual query is fairly trivial. If you're not this far along you should check out some tutorials on SQLAlchemy that cover this subject

Answer (score 0):

The [`execute` method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.execute) can be used to run raw SQL, like so:

```
from sqlalchemy import text
sql = text('select * from candidates1 c inner join uploaded_emails1 e on c.id=e.candidate_id group by e.thread_id')
result = db.engine.execute(sql)
... do stuff ...
```

If you have some models that you're working with, you could use the relationship field type to create a [one-to-many relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) between the Candidate and the UploadedEmail, like so:

```
class Candidate(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'candidates1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    uploaded_emails = relationship("UploadedEmail", lazy='dynamic')

class UploadedEmail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'uploaded_emails1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    candidate_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('candidate.id'))
    thread_id = Column(Integer)
```

And in your code, you might use that like this (including the [group_by](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.group_by))

```
candidate_id = 1
c = Candidate.query.filter_by(id=candidate_id).first()
thread_id_results =  c.uploaded_emails.with_entities(UploadedEmail.thread_id).group_by(UploadedEmail.thread_id).all()
thread_ids = [row[0] for row in thread_id_results]
```

Note that you have to use the `.with_entities` clause to specify the columns you would like to select, and then the fact that you are specifying the thread_id column. If you don't do this, you'll get errors along the lines of "Expression #X of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column ... which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't provide enough information to answer the question. This ended up working:

```
x = db_session.query(Candidate1, Uploaded_Emails1).filter(Candidate1.id == Uploaded_Emails1.candidate_id).group_by(Uploaded_Emails1.thread_id).all()
```